Validate HTTPS requests manually in Qt WebEngine
I'm using Qt WebEngine (Chromium) to load HTTPS pages, which comes with a collection of Certificate Authorities, and I'm able to access Google, etc, without adding any CA.
I want to prevent this and manually validate the request.
The purpose of this is, when a user hasn't installed any CA's, he shouldn't be able to access any HTTPS websites.
How can I achieve this? I was thinking of using onCertificateError, but it gives only the URL and not the client certificate. I'd need the client certificate to validate it with my CA locally.
Can I use QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor?
